# Calcular tarifa total

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Me he lanzado a programar una aplicación para mi hostal con HTML+CSS+PHP+JS, la idea es que los clientes puedan reservar y se les muestre el precio total de la reserva. Pero me he quedado atascado en una cosa:

Necesito calcular el total de mi reserva. En mi base de datos tengo almacenadas las tarifas en una tabla con las siguientes columnas:

precio, habitación, inicio_tarifa, fin_tarifa... Entre otros datos.

Para una habitación dispongo de varias franjas de tarifa con precios distintos, la fecha de inicio de una tarifa se almacena en "inicio_tarifa" y la de fin en "fin_tarifa".

Mediante la siguiente consulta obtengo las tarifas de una determinada habitación:

```
SELECT precio, inicio_tarifa, fin_tarifa from tarifa WHERE habitacion=$_POST[habitacion]
```

Mi problema está en que una reserva puede ocupar varias franjas de tarifa, y no sé como calcular los días de la reserva que están en una determinada franja para multiplicarlos por el precio de esa franja, y así con todas las que ocupe la reserva en cuestión (en caso de que ocupe más de una, puede que en ocasiones coincida con solo una).

Utilizo PHP (sin frameworks) y MySQL.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Que tal hacer la consulta, traerte los montos y haces los cálculos en el controlador?

Comment: Sí, es lo que estoy intentando. El problema es que no logro calcular de forma exacta el precio total de la reserva. Obtengo las fechas de inicio y fin de las franjas de tarifas, así como el precio, pero al intentar calcular X días de la reserva pertenecen a una determinada franja y estos otros X pertenecen a otra para multiplicarlos por su respectivo precio no se como hacerlo. El problema es hallar los días de la reserva que pertenecen a cada franja de tarifas que ocupa la reserva...

Comment: Es decir que el problema que tienes es para totalizar los días y estos días totalizados multiplicarlos al precio para tenerl el monto total de la reserva? Tienes un problema para realizar operaciones con fechas?

Comment: Efectivamente, soy nuevo programando y se me escapan algunas cosillas. Te pongo un ejemplo. Un cliente hace una reserva del 1 septiembre al 20 de septiembre. Yo en mi base de datos tengo un precio del 1 al 5 con un precio 10€/dia, otro del 6 al 11 con un precio 20€/dia y otro del 11 al 20 30€/dia (por ejemplo). Donde me he perdido es cuando consulto las franjas de precios, como obtengo el total de días de la reserva que pertenecen a una franja y cuales a las otras, para así multiplicar los días de cada franja por su precio/día. Sé lo que tengo que hacer pero no como hacerlo en código :(

Comment: Te voy a colocar la respuesta larga para colocar código y tu me dices  si está correcto como te entendí.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Si la respuesta que te di no es la correcta, me avisas y la elimino, por favor.

Comment: Por cierto, cuando buscas ayuda en StackOverflow lo adecuado es que pongas el código con el que estás teniendo problemas, soluciones probadas y errores encontrados. Puedes leer más sobre [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para evitar que tus preguntas reciban malas valoraciones o sean cerradas.

Comment: Hola Benito, gracias por la recomendación. La verdad es que como estaba atracando en esa parte no tengo más que pruebas que he hecho, no sé si valdrían, aunque están mal. Lo único que he llegado a hacer correcto de esa parte de la aplicación es la consulta.

Comment: Fijate Poncex lo que comenta Benito es totalmente cierto, pero tu problema no se va a resolver con un script. Primero tendría que conocer el modelo del negocio para poder ofrecerte una solución real. Por ejemplo si del 1 al 5 de septiembre el precio no cambia con el pasar de los años (puede ser otra fecha) Entonces todo esos precios me los llevo a la base de datos y luego lo que hago es consultarlo con un método y una función con las fechas que el cliente estuvo hospedado.